# Angular directive to determine html attribute key and value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm a quite newbie to angular directives.

I have this code inside a table:

```
<td ng-repeat="column in ic_dashboard.fields2" ng-show="column.visible" sortable="column.field">                            
<a href="#">
    {{row[column.field]}}
</a>
</td>
```

This is how the fields2 are defined at the javascript:

```
this.fields2 = [
                    {id: 1, field: "SUB_FLOW_CHECK", title: "c1", visible: false, edit_type: "select", options: [true, false]}, 
                    {id: 2, field: "Partner", title: "c2", visible: true, edit_type: "text"}, 
                    {id: 3, field: "MAX_OFFERS_DISPLAY", title: "c3", visible: true, edit_type: "number"}]
```

What I want to achieve is to add a specific html attribute and value to the a tag by the value of the edit_type member in fields2. for example, for edit_type: "number", the output should be:

```
<a editable-number="row[column.field]" href="#">
        {{row[column.field]}}
 </a>
```

for edit_type: "text", the output should be:

```
<a href="#" editable-text="row[column.field]" e-step="any">
    {{row[column.field]}}
</a>
```

and so on...

As far as I understand, a directive is needed here, but have no idea how to begin.

Thanks.

Comment: The `link` function of the directive gives you access to the element. If you don't know how to start, then read the guide on writing a directive available in Angular docs. You should try something and if there's an issue, ask a question. Right now your question is: "please write this code I need for me"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe [ng-switch](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSwitch) is what you are looking for. something like:

```
<div ng-switch="column.edit_type">
    <div ng-switch-when="text">
        <a href="#" editable-text="row[column.field]" e-step="any">
            {{row[column.field]}}
        </a>
    </div>
    <div ng-switch-when="number">
        <a editable-number="row[column.field]" href="#">
            {{row[column.field]}}
        </a>
    </div>
    ...and so on
</div>
```

this logic could either be written directly into the template, or inside a custom directive. Read the [directive guide](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) it's great!

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't aware of the ng-switch option! exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

With a directive you could try this:

```
app.directive('myA', function () {
  return {
      restrict: 'A',
      scope:{
        type : '=',
        value: '='
      },
      link: function(scope, element) {
        element.attr('editable-'+scope.type, scope.value);
      }
  };
})
```

And in your HTML:

```
<td ng-repeat="column in fields2" ng-show="column.visible" sortable="column.field">                            
   <a my-a type="column.edit_type" value="row[column.field]">{{row[column.field]}}</a>
</td>
```